# how do I split database models based on a single spreadsheet table (beginner)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, postgresql, database-design

My question is conceptual, I suppose, rather than practical (though I don't mind if the practical makes an appearance).

I'm a graphic designer that is now building a web application at my workplace (a business firm) with Rails + postgresql, in which the premise is to display a list of services stored in a database.  I've been requested to design a spreadsheet table for use by data-entry folk to do the grunt work of copying hard-copy into data, that I can then, in turn, transfer to the database.

The data is to be displayed, sorted, and filtered with JQuery - so the point of the table structure is to lend itself well to that process.  My question is, is it better to split an incoming table of data (from spreadsheets or .csv's) into two in order to separate the data displayed explicitly (i.e., name, description, link, image) from the data that will be used for sorting and filtering (i.e., tags like "location" and "category of service") or best to keep the database table single and the same as the incoming spreadsheet?  Would it be better to just have the first, explicit data table, with several join/juncture tables to store the multiple nonboolean filtering tags?

Or have I gone wrong already in the way I've begun to think about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have given us sufficient info then it sounds like the website will be concerned with just one table of data ie the list of services.

However, I assume a service will contain a category and a location.  These could be stored in the same table as columns containing text descriptions (you do run the risk of input errors though). However, if you are also adding to the categories and the locations then it would make sense to store these as separate tables and build a Query or View to provide the appropriate data to the web application.

If everything is going to be entered via excel then you can use Data Validation to display dropdown lists of categories and locations withing the main Services table.

Personally I would always split data where possible as it will ultimately lead to a cleaner structure and will eliminate input errors.

All of this assumes that you know at least a little about how to structure tables, joins, primary and foreign keys in a database as well as build a query / view.

Good luck

Wing